# Using sqlalchemy scoped_session in theading.Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy, python-3.4

I'm having problems using sqlalchemy together with threading.

```
import queue
import threading

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Sequence
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm.scoping import scoped_session

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', password='%s')>" % (
        self.name, self.fullname, self.password)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

sessionfactory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# called by each thread
def write_name(q, name, sessionfactory):
    session = scoped_session(sessionfactory)
    ed_user = User(name=name, fullname='Power', password='edspassword')
    session.add(ed_user)
    session.commit()
    q.put(name)

names = ["Max", "Austin"]

q = queue.Queue()

for u in names:
    t = threading.Thread(target=write_name, args = (q, u, sessionfactory))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

s = q.get()
```

This results in:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users [SQL: 'INSERT INTO users (name, fullname, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('Max', 'Power', 'edspassword')]
```

but it works fine to add and read data in the main thread. Furthermore I assume I need to use threading over multiprocess because scoped_session uses thread local storage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The main problem is that you can't have multiple connections to a SQLite database that only exists in memory, because each connection will create a new empty database. See the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/sqlite.html#using-a-memory-database-in-multiple-threads) on this. In short, you need to create the engine like this to make sure that is only one instance that can be shared across threads.

```
from sqlalchemy.pool import StaticPool
engine = create_engine('sqlite://:memory:',
    connect_args={'check_same_thread': False},
    poolclass=StaticPool, echo=True)
```

Once you do that, you don't need `scoped_session`, because the point of `scoped_session` is to create one connection per each thread and you specifically can't do that here.

Also, note that you should have only one `scoped_session` instance if you want it to work correctly (with a non-SQLite engine). You should treat it as global variable and then it will be able to handle the thread-local stuff.

Comment: `treat it as global variable and then it will be able to handle the thread-local stuff`. This is the part about `scoped_session` that's totally mind blowing to me. How does it work?

Comment: @rr- It uses [`threading.local()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local) which makes objects available only to the thread that created them. So every time you use your scoped session, it will look into this thread-local storage and if there is a session, it will use it. If not, it will create a new one and store it there for future use. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py) and [here](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py#L1011).